# I want to create a notification that will be triggered when another notification is displayed in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mobile, apple-m1

Basically, I have an application where the user can set the time of the first notification, and the following ones will happen repeatedly. For example, I want to be notified every 8 hours, but the first notification will not be from now on. So I need to create 2 notifications, one for the first one, and as soon as the first one goes off, I need to set a new notification every 8 hours.

A practical example: I will take my medicine at 8 o'clock in the morning, but now it's 5 o'clock, and I want to be notified every 8 hours. The first alarm must be for 8 o'clock from 8 o'clock, that is, 4 o'clock. For that, I made a logic:

[image]

However, the other alarms cannot have the same time as the first one, because, as in the previous example, if I left the same trigger, the alarms would be 11 hours, not 8. I need the first to be 11 hours, and the subsequent numbers of 8 in the example.

I already have the code for the first alarm, however, I can't think of a way to create the subsequent ones, which will keep repeating according to the desired time, for example, 8 in 8, 12 in 12

Comment: I already have a structure that receives the interval times, if the user selects 6 in 6, 8 in 8, etc... This use case is already dealt with, and, if the user selects that he will take the medicine now, it works . My problem is when he chooses a time for the notification, that I need to create more than one, and the second notification depends on the first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup a `BGAppRefreshTask`, which will tell the System to periodically wake your app to run in the **Background** to do something in about 30 seconds, then app is Suspended.
You can set a Refreshing Task every 6 hours to check and make a new Local Push Notification if needed.

Here is the guide: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app

When you setup your local notification:

```
// Create the request
let uuidString = UUID().uuidString // SAVE this one to UserDefault then you can fetch delivered/pending notification if needed.
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, 
            content: content, trigger: trigger)


// Schedule the request with the system.
let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
   if error != nil {
      // Handle any errors.
   }
}
```

Function in your AppDelegate.swift

```
// Here you register it in didFinishLaunching()
BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.example.apple-samplecode.ColorFeed.refresh", using: nil) { task in
     self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
}

// Func to register a next background refresh task
func scheduleAppRefresh() {
   let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com.example.apple-samplecode.ColorFeed.refresh")
   // Fetch no earlier than 15 minutes from now.
   request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15 * 60)
        
   do {
      try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
   } catch {
      print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
   }
}

// Here is where you do your logic when the app runs by background refresh event.
func handleAppRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
   // Schedule a new refresh task.
   scheduleAppRefresh()

   // Create an operation that performs the main part of the background task.
   let operation = RefreshAppContentsOperation() // you dont really need this one, just call your logic here.

   // Ex:
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications {[weak self] listNoti in
       for noti in listNoti {
           if noti.identifier == [your UUID that you just save in UserDefault before] {
               // It delivered, now make new Local notification...
           }
       }
   }
   
   // Provide the background task with an expiration handler that cancels the operation.
   task.expirationHandler = {
      operation.cancel()
   }


   // Inform the system that the background task is complete
   // when the operation completes.
   operation.completionBlock = {
      task.setTaskCompleted(success: !operation.isCancelled)
   }


   // Start the operation.
   operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
 }
```

Comment: What does RefreshAppContentsOperation contain?

Answer (score 0):

Use a repeating [`UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger) for each separate time of day. In your case, that means use three triggers (and therefore three requests): one each at 8, 16, and 0 hours. You don't need to add a separate request for the soonest occurrence.

```
for i in 0 ..< 3 {
    let when = DateComponents(hour: (8 + 8 * i) % 24, minute: 0)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: when, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(
        identifier: "trigger-\(i)",
        content: someContent(),
        trigger: trigger
    )
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if let error = error {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But i want for the same request. imagine that my first alarm has to be set to 10 o'clock, and that same alarm, after going off once after 10 o'clock, needs to be set to 8 o'clock. That is, the same request needs a trigger initially of 10 hours, and after 8 in 8. Or so, I thought of after triggering it in 10 hours, delete it and create one of 8, but I don't know how to do it.